# backand platform: where can I put global methods for DB's Trigger action

Tags: javascript, backand

I want created global method that deal with upload images and create objecs
and call them from `DB's Trigger action` like `User - Create`

where should I put them for I have access to them in the   `DB's Trigger action`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create on-demand actions in Back& that perform this task for you. Pick a relevant object in your system to host the action, then open that object in the Backand dashboard.

[Object Actions tab in Backand Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgYRx.png)

When you click on the Actions tab, you'll see the "On Demand" option as the first element. Hit the green "+" sign to create your action, then write your javascript. Once this is done, you can use the "Save and Test" button to test your action. When this test is completed, you'll be given both the code used to call the action, and a sample response, as follows:

[Action execution code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1orY.png)